# I am trying to assert if two strings of a response are same or not using response assertion in jmeter but it's showing an error

Tags: json, jmeter

In response assertion I have given field to test as text response and pattern matching as contains

Pattern to test is
${bookmark_ALL}${value}=${value}${other_bookmark_ALL}

I have taken those bookmark values using json extractor given match -1 for it as well, both bookmark values are in string format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare 2 [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) the correct setup would be something like:

[image]

You can check JMeter Variables values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

Also `contains` mode assumes regular expression, most probably you were looking for `substring`

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)